# given the real part of 1 root of a polynomial with degree 4, find all the other roots.

Tags: complex-numbers

ive tried - long divsion and equating the remainder to zero, 
and substituting 2 + ib in the equation,

but both are too complex and didnt give me the right answer, which is

$$z = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{5} }{2}$$    and 2 + i and 2 - i

[image])

Comment: What does $$(=0/5(3\pm\sqrt5)$$ mean? It has unbalanced parentheses, as written it's two ways of writing zero, and it's only two roots where the polynomial should have three more.

Comment: I'm so sorry,  i edited it now.

Comment: OK, that's better (though it would be better still if you would take a few minutes with the help menu to learn about formatting mathematics on this website). But I'm still worried that that equation has four solutions, while what you're calling the right answer only comes to two.

Comment: if $2+ib$ is a root, so does $2-ib$, This means the polynomial contains a quadratic factor of the form $z^2-4z+A$. By matching the coeff of $z^3$, the polynomial also contains a factor of the form $z^2+3z+B$. Now compare the coefficients of $z^2, z^1$ and $z^0$ in 
$$z^4 - z^3 - 6z^2 + 11z + 5 = (z^2-4z+A)(z^2+3z+B)$$ You will get $A = 5,B = 1$ and hence obtain 4 roots, two of them $2\pm i$ will be complex, the other two $\frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$ will be real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you substitute $2+bi$ into the equation you get
$$11+7ib-12b^2-7ib^3+b^4=0.$$ So $7ib(1-b^2)=0$ and since $b=0$ is no solution you
have $b=\pm 1$. If you divide your original polynominal by
$(z-(2+i))(z-(2-i)) = z^2 - 4z +5$ you have to solve 
$$z^2+3z+1 =0.$$

Can you continue?